# If $\{T_n\} \to T$ and $\{u_n\} \to u$, then $\{T_n(u_n)\} \to T(u)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed linear spaces. Define 
$$L(X,Y) = \{T:X \to Y \ \big |  \ T \text{ is bounded}\}.$$
Let $\{T_n\} \to T$ in $L(X,Y)$ and $\{u_n\} \to u$ in $X$, then $\{T_n(u_n)\} \to T(u)$ in $Y$.

**Proof:**

Let $T_n, T \in L(X,Y)$ such that $\{T_n\} \to T$ in $L(X,Y)$. Since $T$ and $T_n$ are bounded for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists constant $M_0$ and $M_n$ respectively for which $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$||T(u)|| \leq M_0 ||u|| \quad\forall u \in X,$$
$$||T_n(u)|| \leq M_n ||u|| \quad \forall u \in X.$$
Define $M = \sup_n \{M_n\}$. We claim that $M$ is finite because each linear operator $T_n$ is bounded. Otherwise, $M = \infty$ and thus for some $n$, we have that $M_n = \infty$, so that $T_n$ is unbounded and therefore we obtain a contradiction. Now,
$$||T(u) - T_n(u_n)||= ||T(u) -T_n(u)+T_n(u)- T_n(u_n)||\leqslant \cdots\\ \cdots \leqslant ||T(u) -T_n(u)||+||T_n(u)- T_n(u_n)||\leqslant \cdots \\ \cdots \leqslant  ||T-T_n||.||u|| + M .||u-u_n||.$$
Using taking the limit as $n$ approach infinity and using the fact that $\{T_n\} \to T$ in $L(X,Y)$ and $\{u_n\} \to u$ in $X$, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} ||T(u) - T_n(u_n)|| \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( ||T-T_n||.||u|| + M .||u-u_n||\right) = 0$$
and therefore $\{T_n(u_n)\} \to T(u)$ in $Y$ as required.

Comment: You should probably explain why $M=\sup_nM_n$ is finite.

Comment: It is simpler to consider $$\|T(u)-T_n(u_n)\|=\|T(u)-T(u_n)+T(u_n)-T_n(u_n)\|≤ \|T\| \cdot \|u-u_n\|+ \|T-T_n\|\cdot \|u_n\|$$ and then bound $\|u_n\|$ by something.

Comment: I think the step $M$ can be omitted, since $ \lim_{n \to \infty}||u - u_n|| = 0$

Comment: If $M_n = n^2$, $\|u-u_n\|=\frac1n$, then the term $M_n \|u-u_n\|$ will not converge to zero. You would need to show why $M_n$ is well behaved, for example as @carmichael561 says by showing that it is bounded from above.

Comment: 1. You should define $M = \sup \{M_n\}$ and then explain that $M$ is finite because $\{T_n\} \to T$ in $L(X,Y)$.  2. in the final steps, it would be clearer if you explicitly write $||T(u_n) - T_n(u)|| \leqslant ||T(u_n) - T(u)|| +||T(u) - T_n(u)||$  to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}||T(u_n) - T_n(u)|| = 0$. 3 there are shorter paths to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}||T(u) - T_n(u_n)|| = 0$, as @s.harp has pinte in his first comment above.

Comment: Here is another shoter path (using $M$, after proving it is finite). You might write: $$||T(u) - T_n(u_n)||= ||T(u) -T_n(u)+T_n(u)- T_n(u_n)||\leqslant \\ \leqslant ||T(u) -T_n(u)||+||T_n(u)- T_n(u_n)||\leqslant  \\ \leqslant  ||T-T_n||.||u|| + M .||u-u_n||$$

Comment: @Ramiro I modified my approach but not sure if this is the correct reasoning.

Comment: You wrote "Define $M = \sup_n \{M_n\}$. We claim that $M$ is finite because each linear operator $T_n$ is bounded. Otherwise, $M = \infty$ and thus for some $n$, we have that $M_n = \infty$, so that $T_n$ is unbounded and therefore we obtain a contradiction."  This is an incorrect argument. Each $T_n$ may be bounded, each $M_n$  may be finite and we may have $M=+\infty$.   For instance: consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Take $T_n$ to be multiplication by $n$.  Then all $T_n$ are bounded, $M_n=n$ and $M=0$.

Comment: To prove that $M<+\infty$, you need to use the facts that $T_n \to T$ and $T$ is bounded in addition to the fact that $T_n$ are bounded.

Comment: Here is a way to make argument correct and rigorous:  We claim that $M_n$ can be chosen in such way that $\sup_n \{M_n\}<+\infty$. 

In fact, since $T_n \to T$ in $L(X,Y)$, there is $n_0$, such that for all $n>n_0$, 
$$ \|T_n-T\| < 1$$
So, for all $n>n_0$ , 
$$ \|T_n\| = \|T_n -T+T\|  \leqslant \|T_n-T\| +\|T\|< 1+M_0 $$ 
So we can take, for all $n>n_0$ , $M_n = M_0+1$, and thus we have $\sup_n \{M_n\} = \sup\{M_1,\dots, M_{n_0}, M_0+1\} <+\infty$. 

Define $M = \sup_n \{M_n\}$.